# How to display a string value in a integer cell of DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, formatting

This piece of code is populating a `DataGridView` from a database. `Volunteers.Status` is defined as Integer at database level.

I want to show a string instead the integer number in Status column, but the application fails when I try to set the `DataGridView1.Rows(row.Index).Cells(14).Value` to a string.

```
Error: INACTIVE is not a valid value for Int32
```

**Code**

```
        SQL = "SELECT Volunteers.VolunteerID, Volunteers.NameVol AS Nombre, Volunteers.Surname AS Apellidos, Volunteers.email, Volunteers.Address AS Dirección, " & _
               "Volunteers.ID AS DNI, Volunteers.DateOfBirth AS Fecha, Volunteers.PostalCode AS CP, Volunteers.City AS Ciudad, Volunteers.Province AS Provincia, Volunteers.Phone AS Telefono, " & _
                "Volunteers.Studies AS Estudios, Volunteers.Vehicle AS Vehículo, Volunteers.Clothes AS Camiseta, Volunteers.Status AS Estado FROM Volunteers " & _
                "LEFT JOIN ActivityVolunteer ON Volunteers.VolunteerID = ActivityVolunteer.VolunteerID " & _
                "WHERE ActivityVolunteer.ActivityID = " & IDAct


        Dim ds1 As New DataSet

        Dim DA As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, SQLConnection)

        DA.Fill(ds1)

        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables(0)


        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

            Select Case DataGridView1.Rows(row.Index).Cells(14).Value
                Case 0
                    DataGridView1.Rows(row.Index).Cells(14).Value = "INACTIVE"
                Case 1
                    DataGridView1.Rows(row.Index).Cells(14).Value = "ACTIVE"
                Case 2
                    DataGridView1.Rows(row.Index).Cells(14).Value = "OTHER"

            End Select

        Next
```

**UPDATE:**

Then I tried a trick, making this column invisible and then add an extra column with values based on the hidden column.

```
DataGridView1.Columns(14).Visible = False
DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Estado", "Estado")

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

        DataGridView1.Rows(row.Index).Cells(15).Value = Convert(row.Cells(14).Value)
    Next


Function Convert(ByVal e As Integer) As String
    Select Case e
        Case 0
            Return "INACTIVE"
        Case 1
            Return "ACTIVE"
        Case 2
            Return "OTHER"
    End Select
    Return String.Empty
End Function
```

This change does not throw any exception, but cells on the new column are empty.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: have you tried an integer Enum?  I am not sure how the DGV handles them, but it might use .ToString to show 'Inactive' etc as you want

Comment: @Plutonix It is an Access database and Enum type is not supported

Comment: store an Integer in the DB, but your code can use an Enum.  h4xpace's answer may be able to be collapsed to `Return e.ToString`

Comment: Could you please tell me how to use an `Enum` to achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the sql statement to get the string as you needed like below

```
SELECT  Volunteers.VolunteerID,  StatusString =
      CASE Volunteers.Status   
         WHEN 0 THEN 'INACTIVE'
         WHEN 1 THEN 'ACTIVE'
         ELSE  'OTHER'
      END, ............
FROM ......
```

Comment: Stupid me!! That's is!! Just using nested IIF(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false) as I'm using Access. Thanks dude!!!

Answer (score 1):

This code should not compile at all:

```
Function Convert(ByRef e As Integer) As Integer
    Select Case e
        Case 0
            e = "INACTIVE"
        Case 1
            e = "ACTIVE"
        Case 2
            e = "OTHER"
    End Select
 Return e
End Function
```

You are passing an integer byref...(why?)... and trying to assign it a string value and then return it. You want:

```
Function Convert(ByVal e As Integer) As String
    Select Case e
        Case 0
            return "INACTIVE"
        Case 1
            return "ACTIVE"
        Case 2
            return "OTHER"
    End Select
 return String.Empty
End Function
```

Try this and see what you get. I suspect that the .CellFormatting event is probably not what you should be handling here, but give this a shot.

Comment: I followed your suggestion (see my UPDATE) but the new column still empty.

Comment: Change the handled event to the BindingComplete() before you add and then populate your new column.

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_events(v=vs.110).aspx to understand the event lifecycle of the datagrid. I dont think CellFormatting() is a reliable choice here.